# Binary file not being read properly in Java

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a binary file in Java using the bufferedReader. I wrote that binary-file using "UTF-8" encoding. The code for writing into a binary file:

```
  byte[] inMsgBin=null;
  try {
      inMsgBin = String.valueOf(cypherText).getBytes("UTF-8");
      //System.out.println("CIPHER TEXT:FULL:BINARY WRITE: "+inMsgBin);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(EncDecApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName+ String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm").format(new Date()))+ ".encmsg")) {
      out.write(inMsgBin);
      out.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(EncDecApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }       


System.out.println("cypherText charCount="+cypherText.length());
```

Here 'cypherText' is a String with some content. Total no of characters written in the file is given as 19. Also after writing, when I open the binary file in Notepad++, it shows some characters. Selecting all the content of the file counts to 19 characters in total.

Now when I read the same file using BufferedReader, using the following lines of code:

```
try
        {
        DecMessage obj2= new DecMessage();
          StringBuilder cipherMsg=new StringBuilder();

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
                String tempLine="";
                fileSelect=true;
                while ((tempLine=in.readLine()) != null) {                      
                    cipherMsg.append(tempLine);
                }
            }

System.out.println("FROM FILE: charCount= "+cipherMsg.length());
```

Here the total no of characters read (stored in 'charCount') is 17 instead of 19.

How can I read all the characters of the file correctly?

Comment: I don't see you setting `UTF-8` anywhere in the reading code...

Comment: What is `cyperText`? Is that a UTF-8 string? If it's not ... then the encoding isn't going to work with Java discarding invalid byte sequences and replacing them with a placeholder (And is `cypherText` *is* a `String` ... why are you converting it to `byte[]` to write it to a file? )

Comment: it's still the same. I tried with 

try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath),"UTF8")))

Comment: @DecodingLife what is "UTF8" ? it is UTF-8 . For standards you can use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 . I tried your code it works very well after adding UTF_8 .

Comment: @BrianRoach - No cypherText is not set to UTF-8. Thanks for plotting the same. Can you please help me set it to UTF-8 encoding as I am not able to do so.

Comment: @DecodingLife what, exactly, is `cypherText`? How is it defined and created?

Comment: @BrianRoach - `cypherText` is a String variable which is used to store ascii character of 8-bit long binary sequences. SUppose '10001000' be an 8-bit the binary sequence, program is getting it's equivalent ASCII character and appending into `cypherText` using simple concatination operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the same charset while reading file.

```
   try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(new File(filePath).toPath(),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

---

UPDATE

Now i got your problem. Thanks for the file.

Again : Your file still readable to any text reader like Notepad++ ( Since your characters includes extended and control characters you are seeing those non readable characters . but it is still in ASCII.)

Now back to your problem, You have two problem with your code.

1. While reading file you should specify the Correct Charset. Readers are character readers - Bytes would be convert into characters while reading. If you specify the Charset it would use that else it would use the default system charset. So you should create `BufferedReader` as follows

   try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(new File(filePath).toPath(),
                       StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
2. Second issue, you have characters which includes Control characters. while reading file line by line , by default bufferedReader uses System's default EOL characters and skip those characters. thats why you are getting 17 instead of 19 ( since you have 2 characters are CR). To avoid this issue you should read characters.

   int ch;
               while ((ch = br.read()) > -1) {
                   buffer.append((char)ch);
               }

Overall the below method would return proper text.

```
static String readCyberText() {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(new File("C:\\projects\\test2201404221017.txt").toPath(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
            int ch;
            while ((ch = br.read()) > -1) {
                buffer.append((char)ch);
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And you can test by

```
String s = readCyberText();
    System.out.println(s.length());
    System.out.println(s);
```

and output as

```
19
ia@

m©Ù6ë<«9K()il
```

Note: the length of String is 19, however when it display it just displayed 17 characters. because the console considered as eof and displayed in different line. but the String contain all 19 characters properly.

Comment: @assylias . Yes Files.readAllLines would return List<String> . For this use case we can use this method. But it should be used in caution  to avoid memory issues for larger files.

Comment: @Mani - Thanks for the detailed help Mani but I am still facing the same problem. can you help me setting the default charset to "UTF_8" for all strings as well.

Comment: @DecodingLife - What you meant by setting charset to UTF_8 for all String? . What is the problem you are facing. You need to provide more code to understand the problem if the problem not in the code posted. Setting Charset should happen before JVM starts else it wont take effect.

Comment: @Mani - I am developing an encrypted text using my own algorithm. I am writing the file in UTF-8 charset so that it won't go wrong on different systems as system can have the default encoding of Java, Windows or can have any other charset. Now as plotted by -BrianRoach- (see his comments above)- it could be because CypherText is not in UTF_8 charset. I am not 100% sure about the correctness of his opinion but still I want to try that out as well.

Comment: @Mani -  And content of cypherText is made this way: Take 8-bit long binary sequence(e.g. 10010001) and convert it to its equivalent ASCII character and then append the obtained string into the string variable named cypherText. I am writing content in binary mode to make it unreadable for anyone who opens the file which contains the content of cypherText.

Comment: @DecodingLife - How are you converting binary seqeunce ( byte) into ASCII character ? and when you say append ? how are you appending ( using + ? or any StringBuffer.append ?) . if possible post our code. reason is it does matter how your cypherText formed.

Comment: @Mani - `String a="10101001"; cypherText+=(char)obj1.asc(a);`. The function `asc` is working perfectly so you need not worry about its working and its returning an `Integer`. Since the maximum value offered by String `a` can only be 11111111 which equals to 2^8-1 which is perfectly stored in an `Integer` variable so that wont be a problem as well.

Comment: @Mani - Value contained in `String a` above is just an example.

Comment: @DecodingLife - i tried to simulate the way you are doing. but still it working fine . see the update. try to execute that.

Comment: Why are you doing  String.valueOf(cyberText) when cyberText already an String ?

Comment: @Mani - There's some file reading issue I guess. When I open the file in Notepad++ after writing it into binary-mode the contents I can see is: `ia@

m©Ù6ë<«9K()il`. Here you can see the second line..it's filled with some character and on counting the whole thing it's summing upto 19characters.

Comment: @Mani - When I read the contents of the file using buffered reader I think it's skipping the second line (the characters of second line looks just empty but actually are taken by some character) and hence the total no of characters read is just 17 and not 19 because it's not able to read the second line which contains 2 characters. I can say that the second line (which seems to be blank contains 2 characters because on selecting that line in Notepad++ it's saying in the status bar of the editor that the selection is of 2 characters). I dont know how can I share the file with you here.

Comment: @Mani - **https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuppgtobn9c66cl/test2201404221017.encmsg** check this file and open it in notepad++. Check out the second line of the file.

Comment: @Brian Roach - Take a look at the file I am getting after writing in binary mode. **dropbox.com/s/uuppgtobn9c66cl/test2201404221017.encmsg**

Comment: @Mani - Actually there are two consecutive carriage returns int the file. While reading since buffered reader is reading a line only upto once it receives a `\n` so its skipping these two lines I think. Can u suggest a solution for this?

Comment: @DecodingLife - i did update my answer based on your comments

Comment: @Mani - Thanks a lot. I was just looking for that but wasn't on mind coz of staying away from Java for a long time. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @DecodingLife . Welcome - Glad to know your problem resolved :)